# event.target not working on IE in case of canvas or cufon tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, cufon

```
$(document).bind('click', function(event) {

alert(event.target);

});
```

this alert is not working in IE if I click on below anchor tag:

```
<h4><a href="www.google.com"><cufon><canvas></canvas><cufontext>Economi</cufontext></ cufon></a></h4>
```

Its because the cufon image is forming the link test.

I m getting the js error saying:

> 'Attribute only valid on v:image js error fix'

Can any one help to resolve this issue quickly?

Comment: Quick fix. Use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ instead of Cufon.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove `hover: 'true'` attribute in `Cufon.replace`. So, I changed it from

```
 Cufon.replace('.cufon_helvetica', {fontFamily: 'Helvetica', hover: 'true'});
```

to

```
 Cufon.replace('.cufon_helvetica', {fontFamily: 'Helvetica'});
```